# Databricks reading from a zip file

Tags: zip, databricks, azure-databricks

I have mounted an Azure Blob Storage in the Azure Databricks workspace filestore. The mounted container has zipped files with csv files in them.
I mounted the data using dbuitls:

```
dbutils.fs.mount(
source = f"wasbs://{container}@{storage_account}.blob.core.windows.net",
mount_point = mountPoint,
extra_configs = {f"fs.azure.sas.{container}.{storage_account}.blob.core.windows.net":sasKey})
```

And then I followed the following tutorial:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/_static/notebooks/zip-files-python.html

But in above since shell command does not work probably because the data does not reside in dbfs but blob storage which is mounted, which gives the error:

```
unzip:  cannot find or open `/mnt/azureblobstorage/file.zip, /mnt/azureblobstorage/Deed/file.zip.zip or /mnt/azureblobstorage/file.zip.ZIP.`
```

What would be the best way to read the zipped files and write into a delta table?

Comment: Can you please share what you have tried and error if you are getting any?

Comment: @PratikLad edited the question above with details, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "zip" utility in unix does work.  I will walk thru the commands so that you can code a dynamic notebook to extract zips files.  The zip file is in ADLS Gen 2 and the extracted files are placed there also.

Because we are using a shell command, this runs at the JVM know as the executor not all the worked nodes.  Therefore there is no parallelization.

[image]

We can see that I have the storage mounted.

[image]

The S&P 500 are the top 505 stocks and their data for 2013.  All these files are in a windows zip file.

[image]

Cell 2 defines widgets (parameters) and retrieves their values.  This only needs to be done once.  The call program can pass the correct parameters to the program

Cell 3 creates variables in the OS (shell) for both the file path and file name.

[image]

In cell 4, we use a shell call to the unzip program to over write the existing directory/files with the contents of the zip file.  This there is not existing directory, we just get the uncompressed files.

[image]

Last but not least, the files do appear in the sub-directory as instructed.

To recap, it is possible to unzip files using databricks (spark) using both remote storage or already mounted storage (local).  Use the above techniques to accomplish this task is a note book that can be called repeatedly.

Comment: Thanks. I was also able to use python package zipfile to achieve the same using the extractall() function from the mounted blob storage location. And the shell command you have provided works as well. Although I'm not sure which would be more efficient in case of large(>20 Gb) files

Comment: I suggest doing testing.  Both will run at the executer node.  I bet you there is not much of a difference.  The cool thing about this technique is you now can leverage any UNIX package / utility.  Want to create a tar ball or process image files with ffmpeg.exe?  Just go for it.

Comment: @CRAFTYDBA - I followed your approach and it works, but it is extremely slow, especially when you have large number of zip files with big sizes. Is there another way of achieving this in Databricks as efficient as Data Factory for example ?

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, gzip is natively supported by spark.  However, it might be slow or chew up a-lot of memory using dataframes.  See this article on rdd's.

https://medium.com/@parasu/dealing-with-large-gzip-files-in-spark-3f2a999fc3fa

On the other hand, if you have a windows zip file you can use a unix script to uncompress the files and then read them.  Check out this article.

https://docs.databricks.com/external-data/zip-files.html

Comment: gzip would probably not work in my case as the files are in zip format with multiple files within them. The tutorial on the other link you provided is something I tried but in that, external file is being downloaded in dbfs after which it is unzipped and read. I have a Azure blob storage mount for which that method does not seem to work.